# iOS Button not work in custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

There are two custom views - viewA and viewB.ViewB is a small view added in viewA. At first viewA is filled in the whole screen. ViewB is located in the bottom of viewA(out of the screen). When click a button in viewA, viewB bottom constant of constraints will be -100, thus viewB will display in the bottom of the screen. But there is a button in viewB did not response its selector. Here is my code:

In ViewA

```
let viewB: ViewB = {
    let view = ViewB(
    view.setup()
    return view
}()
```

viewB constraints:

```
    viewB.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.trailing.leading.equalTo(self)
        make.height.equalTo(100)
        make.top.equalTo(self.snp.bottom)
    }
```

when click button to arouse viewB

```
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.snp.updateConstraints({ (make) in
                make.bottom.equalTo(-100)
            })
        }
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

In viewB:

```
class ViewB: UIView {

let b: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
    return button
}()


func btnClicked() {
   print("btnClicked")
}

func setup() {
    addSubview(b)
    b.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.top.bottom.equalTo(self)
        make.width.equalTo(100)
    }

}
}
```

[image: View Debugger]

Comment: where the code your button frame you set ?

Comment: button.frame = CGRect(button_x_position,Button_y_position,your_button_width , your_button_hight) add this line after your let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) and check output

Comment: Is the button visible? If yes check if there is another view overlapping your `UIButton` in the debug view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code by itself works fine. So the issue is probably something like the button being overlaid by another view which takes the touch actions. You can test this using the view debugger or provide a link to your project so one of us can take a look to see what is going on.

Comment: OK if you can't figure out the issue, then I'd suggest posting a link to the full project (not just the code snippets) so that I (or somebody else) can run the project and tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks to you, I've found viewB is out of boundary.

Comment: Great to hear you were able to sort it out yourself :) Those are always the best cases - at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

i think , your view is going out of its super View or Any other view is coming on its upper layer. please see by this

```
superview.clipsToBounds :  YES
```